# How to get started with Video-To-Texture rendering?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal

I have a video that is downloaded and retrieved as `NSData*` (will be a `NSInputStream*` later).

The file format is irrelevant for now.
I would like to render this video onto a 3D Object via a **MTLTexture** (or an equivalent counterpart for videos).

I am unaware to see where to start this since there seem to be an endless variation of classes in the **AVFoundation Framework** aswell as in the **CoreGraphics Framework**. Can you help me to see the relevant classes I need to use?

Comment: The pivotal class for achieving this is `CVMetalTextureCache`, which allows you to efficiently convert from `CVPixelBuffer`s (which are easily obtained from an `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` and various other types) to `MTLTexture`s. From there, it's just a matter of binding the resulting texture and rendering with it. As there are many resources online for each aspect of this, you should consider researching those and asking narrower questions as you encounter difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @warrenm, I've found the correct solution.
Here are parts of my `VideoPlayer` class

```
-(instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, [[Renderer sharedInstance] renderDevice], nil, &self->_textureCache);
            NSError* error1;
            NSString* mimeType = @"video/mp4";
            NSArray* keys = @[@"tracks"];
            AVAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:@{@"AVURLAssetOutOfBandMIMETypeKey" : mimeType}];
            [videoAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{
               [self onVideoLoaded:videoAsset];
            }
        ];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)onVideoLoaded:(AVAsset*)videoAsset {
    NSError* error;
    AVKeyValueStatus status = [videoAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
    switch (status) {
        //error handlings
    }
    NSDictionary* settings = @{(id) kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)};
    [self setVideoPlayerOutput:[[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:settings]];
    [self setVideoPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:videoAsset]];
    [[self videoPlayerItem] addOutput:[self videoPlayerOutput]];
    [self setVideoPlayer:[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:[self videoPlayerItem]]];
    [[self videoPlayer] setVolume:1.0f];
    [self setIsLoaded:YES];
}
```

to get the texture, I have this function:

```
-(id <MTLTexture>)getCurrentFrameTexture {
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [[self videoPlayerOutput] copyPixelBufferForItemTime:[[self videoPlayerItem] currentTime] itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
    NSUInteger width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(buffer);
    NSUInteger height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer);
    NSUInteger planeCount = CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(buffer);
    CVMetalTextureRef textureRef;
    CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, [self textureCache], buffer, nil, MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB, width, height, planeCount, &textureRef);
    id <MTLTexture> tex = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(textureRef);
    CVBufferRelease(textureRef);
    CVBufferRelease(buffer);
    return tex;
}
```

This also works with streaming, just supply a valid mp4 url. The file is not downloaded or anything